# Driver issues with windows 7 re-installation

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio, drivers, graphics-card

My copy of Windows 7 crashed. It refused to start, and all options to restore windows failed to work. I reinstalled windows, only to find that under windows.old, all my old files were still on my hard drive. I have a MSI motherboard and an AMD CPU and ATI graphics card. I have my Ethernet drivers working, and have installed the "chipset" drivers. But once I try to install the Realtek Audio drivers, this happens.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lrtd0.png)

Past this, there are still video drivers that I can't install for some strange reason, the autodetect utility from ATI just doesn't actually download the drivers.

Anyone know what steps to take aside from a new hard drive?

SPECS:

Motherboard: MSI A78M-E35 Micro ATX FM2+ Motherboard

Graphics card: MSI Radeon R9 270X 2GB Video Card

Processor: AMD Athlon X4 760K 3.8GHz Quad-Core Processor

Storage: Seagate Barracuda 1TB 3.5" 7200RPM Internal Hard Drive

Comment: Have you tried [removing the windows.old folder](http:// www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/19151-windows-old-folder-delete.html) I would suggest for a clean installation rather than finding workarounds. You may backup necessary data before doing so.

Comment: I've already just gone ahead and formatted my c drive

Comment: It seems like my video card is back up, since I can run LoL at 200fps on max settings. It's just the realtek driver. 
fps screenshot: http://imgur.com/EsP107E
no output device: http://imgur.com/Xf09KEv
realtek driver failed install: http://imgur.com/VuW7xqQ

Comment: Okay, I would suggest you to remove the comments that are irrelevant. Now, open device manager (Start-type `device manager` - click on the first in list) In View on menu bar, select `show hidden devices`. Now scroll down the device list under `sound , video and game controllers`. What all do you see? Does anything have a yellow badge over it?

Comment: Yes, this is what came up exactly.
http://imgur.com/o7f3C9p

edit: do you prefer screenshots or descriptions?

Comment: Its your take to describe or post a screenshot. You can use **snipping tool** in latter case. From the last screen shot, can you right click the AMD entry and click uninstall? It may prompt for restart, deny it. Now right click on the other entry and select `update driver software `- try the first option, if it fails, use the second one, browse to the folder where the driver is stored. Check in BIOS/UEFI to make sure HD audio is enabled. Try going into safe mode to install the audio driver.

Comment: You must download the driver for audio from MSI website corresponding to the model before that. Have you installed all drivers including that of graphics card and other necessary software?

Answer (score 0):

I understand you do not want to hear this, but I cannot help but think the best option is to re-install on a new hard drive if you want to keep all the old files.

You can find a hard drive for pretty cheap these days, ideally you want to boot off of a SSD anyway.

hopefully you do not have an issue preventing you from putting additional hard drives into your computer. Even if you had those issues I would still recommend this, and to get a usb hard drive dock to read the old hard drive and transport the information from there to the new installation.

Good luck.

Comment: Do you think there's something wrong with my hard drive? Corruption, or something wrong with the head? All my problems seem to be driver related.

Comment: possible, but certainly not probable. I would not think that is the reason for having driver issues.